# How to decode the flask response with message pack?

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, msgpack

I'm using message pack to encode the flask response before sending it to the UI. In order to do that I'm overriding the flask response class

```
from flask import Flask, Response, jsonify, make_response
import msgpack
import json
class FlaskResponse(Response):
    @classmethod
    def force_type(cls, rv, environ=None):
        if isinstance(rv, dict):
            rv = jsonify(rv)
        msgData = super(FlaskResponse, cls).force_type(rv, environ)
        print "msgData"
        print msgpack.packb(json.loads(msgData.data))
        return jsonify((msgpack.packb(json.loads(msgData.data))))
```

I'm getting the error

> ```
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 0: invalid start byte
> ```

Any suggestion what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Which output are you expect? Can you add endpoint?

Comment: from the endpoint I'm returning the dictionary

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you are trying to send packed bytes to `jsonify` function, but Flask doesn't work with it structure. I can recommend to set data to `FlaskRequest` after instance creation.

```
from flask import Flask, Response, jsonify
import msgpack


class CustomResponse(Response):

    @classmethod
    def force_type(cls, response, environ=None):
        # create response instance with empty data
        flask_response = jsonify()  # type: CustomResponse
        if isinstance(response, dict):
            # set some data to respose
            flask_response.data = msgpack.packb(response)
            # set content_type etc...
            # flask_response.content_type = 'application/octet-stream'

        print(flask_response.data)
        # we return response object so we don't need super()
        return flask_response


app = Flask(__name__)
app.response_class = CustomResponse


@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return {
        'example_dict': {
            'container_name': 'test',
            'id': 100,
        },
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @GauravSharma I think yes